# Creating folders based on filename using Python

Tags: python

I have about one million files in a folder that I want to organize into folders based on part of the file name using Python. Some examples of the file names are included below. I want to create a folder for each file type based on the information after the first '_' and before the second '_'.

19930813_10-Q_edgar_data_60512_0000060512-94-000005_1

19931007_10-K-A_edgar_data_60512_0000060512-94-000006_1

So for the first file, I want to create a folder named '10-Q' and for the second '10-K-A'. I know that there are several similar queries but they are mostly for other programming languages and not Python. Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I know that there are several similar queries but they are mostly for other programming languages and not Python." Add `[python]` to your search query. Anyway, what exactly don't you know how to do? Are you able to split up the string? Are you able to create folders with a provided name?

Comment: Thank you Karl. I have added Python to my query. I can split the file names but I do not know how to create folders based on the splits.

`import os

os.chdir('D:/EDGAR/')

for f in os.listdir():
 f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
 f_date, f_type = f_name.split('-')`

Comment: Once you have put together the desired complete path for the folder you want to create, the relevant call is `os.mkdir`.

Comment: I don't understand. So once I have split the file names, how can I create a folder based on those file names and how do I then move the files containing the file name pattern into those folders?

Comment: You use ordinary string manipulation to create the path name, according to the logic that tells you what the folder name should be based on the file name, and then you use that to make the `os.mkdir` call. Then you can move the files around as appropriate. Try also reading the documentation for the `os` and `shutil` modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this code, hope it will work :

```
import os
import shutil

folder_path = 'The folder containing files'
file_types = []
for file in (os.listdir(folder_path)):
    file_type_part_name_by_ = file.split('_')
    file_type = file_type_part_name_by_[1]
    if file_type not in file_types:
        file_types.append(file_type)
        os.mkdir(file_type)
        shutil.move(file, file_type)
    else:
        shutil.move(file, file_type)
```

---